# A secure way for a PHP variable to be used in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, security

My code is as follows (simplified):

```
$items_per_view = 5;
$items_per_scroll = 1;

$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>
                jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {         
                    $(document).ready(function() {                            
                       $('#$uniqid').slick({                      
                          slide: 'li',
                          slidesToShow: $items_per_view,
                          slidesToScroll: $items_per_scroll,                     
                        });                 
                    });
                }
             );
            </script>";     

    $output .= $script;
```

Now I've been reading a lot about using *Escaping Attributes* as best practice. However when I tried to use `json_encode( $items_per_view )` or `esc_js( $items_per_view )`, it stops working and in Chrome I see a message saying "json_encode is not defined". I also tried using `wp_json_encode` but that didn't worked either.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Please share all code;

Comment: So what exactly do you want to secure? It's safe to put numbers into your JS as-is.

Comment: Actually, I simplified the code. `$items_per_view` is actually a redux (framework) field. But it seems that all their fields are automatically sanitized. So seeing that it's safe like this, we'll keep it at that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [JSON mod extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) for PHP.

Depending on your OS and installation type, google a bit for the installation procedure.

Comment: I'm on Wordpress, so it should be possible even without installing JSON.

Comment: It's not regarding Wordpress. It's regarding the PHP extensions required by wordpress to run. Wordpress 3.3.1 needs:
JSON - 20 uses
optional, fallbacks in wp-includes/compat.php

Comment: Additionally you can run <?php phpinfo(); ?> to check the status.